# Результат подзапроса, в качестве имени таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Хочу получить данные из таблицы, имя которой хранится в другой таблице.
Пробовал так

```
select *
from (
select alias from stack_alias
where stack = 21
) as st
```

но это возвращает данные из таблицы в подзапросе.

Comment: Для MySQL - только динамический SQL. [Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). PS. Лучше подумать об изменении структуры БД.

Comment: Я не думаю, что есть диалект SQL, который такое позволяет. Какого типа возвращаемые данные? Какие колонки? Как планировщику строить запрос? Зависимых типов в SQL нет.